# How to show html content in email with jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jobs

I want to send a site monitor report by email when I run a job. I saved the generated report as html and I changed the job number as `$BUILD_NUMBER` (Every time I triggered the job I changed to get the current report).

I gave it as default content `${FILE,path="/target/url.html"}` in Email-ext plugin.
When I send the mail, the contents are broken because Jenkins CSS, JavaScript files are not local.

How can I solve this situation? Is there another way?

Comment: Go for `mailhog` docker image , it is a SMTP email server. which gives you good leverage in form of UI.